# Drupal Answers Top User Swag

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are (as of July 2) on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Drupal Answers t-shirt in your size
- Drupal Answers die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: drupal.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: drupal.stackexchange.com sticker]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)</sub>

Comment: Cool! After following the shortened url to hanes, I cannot find the "product specs" sidebar that will supposedly tell me more about the t-shirt sizes.

Comment: @Letharion Here, try this link instead: http://haneslocator.com/Library/SizeChart.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I can't wait to sport some swag this fall!

Comment: Thats awesome! Too bad i'll never get there. @Clive is too much of a badass to catch on the scoreboard =D

Comment: Thats awesome! I love it.

Comment: Cool, I thought these things were an urban legend! Thanks very much, I shall wear the T-shirt with pride and plaster my car with the stickers ;)

Comment: hah, those women's sizes make absolutely no sense. :p

Comment: I will wear this every day to work until it breaks, and to every future interview (especially those that require you to wear ties) :P

Comment: Thanks! 8 more to go...

Comment: Got mine yesterday, thanks guys :)

Comment: Awesome! Can we expect DA top user swag this year?  :)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan We usually just print it once to celebrate a site's graduation.

Answer (score 4):

I got them all. 
There are some untold items also.
[image]
Thanks StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

I envy you. Still haven't got mine. Even for overseas shipment, which is my case, the delay seems long enough to think I'm not going to get these goodies ever ever. :( Listen to the teardrops...

Comment: Hmm. The best I can find out from the tracking info is that your package got shipped. Drop me an email (the address is in my profile) to confirm your mailing address and we'll try again.